# What is the output of a quantum simulator?

Tags: simulations, quantum-computer

First off the bat, the context of this question is philosophical, but please don't run away, since a physicist is required to comment on this one:

Philosophers sometimes contemplate a hypothetical Turing Machine simulating a brain or an environment including a brain; for example, in [*A Computational Foundation for the Study of Cognition*](http://cogprints.org/319/1/computation.html), David Chalmers wrote:

> We have every reason to believe that the low-level laws of physics are
>   computable. If so, then low-level neurophysiological processes can be
>   computationally simulated; it follows that the function of the whole
>   brain is computable too, as the brain consists in a network of
>   neurophysiological parts.

Lets say physicists will one day be able to simulate a brain as a huge quantum system, (yes I know it is ridiculously huge with about 10^26 atoms).

what does such a simulation compute?

is it the probabilities of all possible future states of the system at a particular time?

an answer intelligible by a layperson would be appreciated